# Problems with deepcopying sys.stdout in python

Tags: python

I have the following problem with copy.deepcopy. It is to do with deepcopying sys.stdout

```
import sys, copy

class Example:
  def __init__(self, value, outa=sys.stdout):
    self.value = value
    self.outa = outa
  def saying_hello_world(self):
    print>>self.outa, "Hello world! My value is ", self.value

example_1 = Example(3)
example_1.saying_hello_world()

example_2 = copy.deepcopy(example_1)
example_2.value = 5
example_2.saying_hello_world()
```

Leads to error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "<stdin>", line 6, in saying_hello_world
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

For various reasons I need to deepcopy (as I change example_2 in various ways in my more complex situation, and so need a deepcopy). However, when it deepcopies `sys.stdout`, it transfers it from outputting into thee screen and instead outputs it to a closed file, which then gets the error above. An obvious solution to this is

```
example_2 = copy.deepcopy(example_1)
example_2.outa = example_1.outa
```

Is there a better way around this? Or a better way of deepcopying? Thank you!

Comment: in that particular case `copy` would be enough. Bad idea to copy file descriptors...

Comment: The actual class I am having is significantly larger than the above, and I need a deep copy. Is there a way of not deep copying file descriptors, but deep copying everything else, @Jean-FrançoisFabre ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own mechanism for deepcoping object using magicmethod `__deepcopy__`

Here is working example for your code:

```
import sys, copy

class Example:
  def __init__(self, value, outa=sys.stdout):
    self.value = value
    self.outa = outa

  def saying_hello_world(self):
    print>>self.outa, "Hello world! My value is ", self.value

  def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
      # deepcopy self.value, but pass just a reference of self.outa
      return Example(copy.deepcopy(self.value, memo), self.outa)


example_1 = Example(3)
example_1.saying_hello_world()

example_2 = copy.deepcopy(example_1)
example_2.value = 5
example_2.saying_hello_world()
```

It is not ideal (you'll need care if subclassing this, as deepcopy of child will return instance of parent!) but should give you an idea how to implement this in your real life application.

Comment: Indeed, an interesting case. However, it is dangerous, and laborious if you increase the size of the class, or want to make a child from it. However it is an interesting solution, though I feel my original idea might be safer... I'll leave this question open over the weekend, and if I don't get any other replies, I will accept yours.

Comment: for subclassing or extending your class you can extend `__deepcopy__` method to copy everything except some blacklisted attrs (or actually do any magic you need to do)

Answer (score 0):

You can customise how your instances are copied, and just share the output if it is `sys.stdout`, using the `__deepcopy__` method:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, value, outa=sys.stdout):
        self.value = value
        self.outa = outa
    def saying_hello_world(self):
        print >> self.outa, "Hello world! My value is ", self.value
    def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
        outa = self.outa if self.outa is sys.stdout else deepcopy(self.outa, memo)
        return Example(deepcopy(self.value, memo), outa)
```

You can adjust the logic for when to copy the `outa` attribute; perhaps not copying anything that is an open file object is a good idea, for example, or *never* copying that attribute.